# Affect neighboring divs on both side on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar, `.navbar`, that has 7 direct children, `navbar-item`.

Currently, I made it so when you hover over a navbar item, it would increase it's width and height by 20px. But what I want is that when you hover over one of the items, it would increase it's height and width by 20px, and it would increase it's **Directly Neighboring** divs, (so the left and right divs, unless it is on on the edge), width and height by 10px.

A great example of what I want is like the macOS app bar effect.

Code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.navbar {
    width: 600px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.navbar-item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.navbar-item:hover{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to use `.navbar-item:hover + .navbar-item`, but that just changed the width and height of the div to the right of the one actually being hovered on.

I read this question: [How to affect other elements when one element is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered)

But it did not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:has()` selector can help you here. I am using scale instead of width/height but not relevant to the main trick

```css
body {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.navbar {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.navbar-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .3s;
}

.navbar-item:hover { /* main element */
  scale: 1.5;
}
/* direct neighbors */
.navbar-item:hover + *,
.navbar-item:has(+ .navbar-item:hover){
  scale: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
  <div class="navbar-item"></div>
</div>
```